# Django best practice to show other related models in a view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to loop over a related model and show other properties in that model, which includes other relationships, but am having trouble showing that in a view. Any tips would be much appreciated.

```py
# model.py
class Model1(models.Model):
    entry = models.TextField(default='')

class Model2(models.Model):
    info = models.TextField(default='')

class Model3(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model2 = models.ForeignKey(Model2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.TextField(default='')
```

```py
# views.py
class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = 'o'
        results = Model1.objects.filter(model3__value__icontains=q).distinct('id')

        context = {
            'results': results,
        }

        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

```html
# index.html
{% for result in results %}
  <div>
    <p>{{ result }}</p>
    {% for m in result.model1.all %}
      <p>
        {{ m.value }}: {{ m.model2.info}}
      </p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
Sample data for Model1:
id | entry
1  | entry-1
2  | entry-2
3  | entry-3

Sample data for Model2:
id | info
1  | info-1
2  | info-2

Sample data for Model3:
id | model1 | model2 | value
1  | 1      | 1      | lorem
2  | 1      | 2      | ipsum
3  | 2      | 1      | foo
4  | 3      | 1      | bar
```

```
Sample preferred output assuming q = o
1
lorem: info-1
ipsum: info-2

2
foo: info-1
```

```
What actually happens assuming q = o
1
lorem:
ipsum:

2
foo:
```

```
Mapping the sample models to a more tangible relationship:
Model1 - Author
Model2 - Language
Model3 - Book

So the goal would be a view showing:
author-1
lorem: language-1
ipsum: language-2

author-2
foo: language-1
```

This is a simplification of the actual dataset but hopefully there's enough there. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks much in advance.

## Update

After many tweaks and trying out *Deniz Kaplan's* suggestions, I managed to get it to work. The only adjustment I made was:

```
results = Model1.objects.filter(model1__value__icontains=q).distinct('id')
```

Here's a slight modification to try to be more efficient:

```
 results = Model1.objects.prefetch_related('model1').filter(model1__value__icontains=q).distinct('id')
```

In case this seems confusing to anyone, the lowercase `model1` represents the relationship between Model1 and Model3, aka `Model3.model1`.

Comment: where from did you get m1 in your {{ m1.model2.info}}, also is this  {% for m3 in result.model3.all %}

Comment: It would be easier that you name your models, you have made errors in template when translating to this "fake" model names

Comment: @iklinac Oops, yes, that should be m3, not m1. Fixed.

Comment: @iklinac I added an example at the end of the question. See if that helps.

Comment: You haven't answered my second question, i understand what you want to achieve but you should write correct template as  result.model1.all does not have sense if you are querying for Model1 in results

Comment: @iklinac The names are what I have tried. The example maps from sample name to actual names.

Comment: Cleaned up a little more. The idea is that Model1 represents an author, Model2 represents a language, and Model3 is a book, which is described to have an author and a language. An author can write many books. Many books share the same language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating a sample project, I just figured out that it is the view that we need to change first:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

from book.models import Author


# Create your views here.
class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = 'o'
        author_qs = Author.objects.filter(book__value__icontains=q)
        # this is the part we need to update to group query by author
        query = author_qs.query
        query.group_by = ["id"]

        context = {
            'results': author_qs,
        }

        return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

Then I can manage to show them groupped by author information.

```
# index.html file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Authors</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for author in results %}
    <li>{{ author.entry }}
    <ul>
        {% for book in author.book_set.all %}
          <li>{{ book.value}}: {{ book.language.info }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I did not spend time on html parts but I think this will be enough for you.

Comment: `regroup` could work. In that link that you provided, their example uses country-city-population. That's close to what I'm looking for except what if population is actually another model and not a regular number/text field as part of the city? What if instead of population, it's another related model called language?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#grouping-on-other-properties you can write your own regroup method to do that. If you have all information in queryset, you can do that with a custom function.

Comment: I'll give that a try and see how it works. May ask for additional tips as, needless to say, Python in general is new to me.

Comment: So I'm probably using regroup completely off. I tried something like:
`
{% regroup results by model1 as results_list %}
{% for model1, model2 in results_list %}
<p>{{ model1 }} : {{ model2}}</p>
{% endfor %}
`
However, the output was `Model3.None : [<Entry: 1>]` and I couldn't get any properties from Model2.

Comment: Answered in a comment above but if it helps, the idea is that Model1 represents an author, Model2 is a language, and Model3 is a book, which is described to have an author and a language. An author can write many books. Many books share the same language. The template should show the search results of books with the ultimate goal of each card in the results showing a book and its properties, such as author and language. I may be constructing the model/view/template inefficiently so if there's a different approach that is recommended, please feel free to recommend a different overall approach.

Comment: I have updated my answer with model names. I hope this approach will help you. Generally it is best practice to choose base class as your requirements need. In this case, I understand that you need book results in template, so that should be the base model to query.

Comment: Ok, great. Thank you. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I am a bit confused too. I will create a sample Django project to check that I can create author cards with books and languages. I just noticed that you have updated excepted result in your question. That will be my aim to show.

Comment: I made a mistake in my goal above and the goal is each card to show all of each author's books. That said, I tried out the recommendation and after figuring out a typo, what I've got now is that the view is showing the {{result}} as the first matched book by each author but nothing in the loop. It doesn't make sense to me that the inner loop should be over result.model1.all since that would be only for that particular book but I'm not sure how else to find and show the rest of the author's book for each card.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: I tried it out but got similar results. The inner `for book in author.book_set.all` loop doesn't seem to work. That loop doesn't display anything at all. Were you able to get that to work? I checked multiple times and I think I followed your suggestion but I could've made a mistake in my test. Also, wouldn't `group_by` have similar results as `distinct('id')`?

Comment: Thanks so much Deniz Kaplan for your help. With your suggestions and thinking through and trying multiple options, I managed to get it to work. As is often the case, it was a very small adjustment. Original post has been updated with the solution that worked.